# Can't find Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.dll

Tags: c#, sharepoint, web-applications

I'm trying to add `Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls` as reference in my C# WebApplication. But I'm not able to find it when I search in the assemblies list. And it's nowhere on my computer. Do I have to download it? If yes, where? I cannot find any useful download link.

I'm stuck on this, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.aspx) namespace (`Microsoft.SharePoint.dll`) is a component of SharePoint Server/Foundation product.

In order to develop applications using [Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.aspx) namespace, SharePoint Server/Foundation has to be installed on the machine.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I hope these two links will help:

download:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35585

informations: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/afe4d365-1060-45aa-ac17-354878aaa3c7/include-microsoftsharepointdll-into-c-project-net-40-client-profile-or-greater?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already installed the SharePoint Server 2013 Client Components SDK but it didn't help, the reference is still not available. And the msdn thread couldn't help me neither :/

Comment: @Tyler If you download the Windows Installer package and open it with 7Zip you see the "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll" and "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll". Add these two libraries in your project and make sure that you have the correct **Target Framework**.

Comment: I added these two ddls and my target framework is .NET 4, but I'm still unable to use the WebControls reference.